# CSS - Alinhar texto ao centro da tela, ultrapassando o tamanho da div?

Tags: html, css

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho uma DIV localizada ao centro da tela, com posição absoluta. Pretendo colocar um texto no meio dela, que caso ele seja maior do que a div, ultrapasse seus limites da direita e da esquerda, assim como na foto acima. É possível fazer isso? Irei fazer a substituição de um texto por outro sempre, então não posso simplesmente definir manualmente uma margin-left, por exemplo.

```
<div class="pai">
  <p>Texto aqui para ultrapassar a div</p>
</div>
```

```
.pai{
position: absolute;
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível sim, basicamente vc precisa colocar um `no-wrap` no `<p>`

```css
.pai {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;

  /* centraliza o texto no pai */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

/* não deixa o texto quebrar linha */
.pai > p {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="pai">
  <p>Texto aqui para ultrapassar a div</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Nesse caso o texto ultrapassa a div apenas no lado direito, também preciso no esquerdo, como faço?

Comment: @Tester. como assim amigo, ultrapassa dos dois lados... olha ai https://prnt.sc/y1mble não entendi o que vc quer dizer